# Motor MnM torque max weight can spin circular object

Tags: motors

Here's is my problem I am trying to spinal object at high speeds
My motors watts is 242.42
My motor max speed is 70,000 rpm
My circular rotating object that will be right on motor is 60grams
My motor torque is 35 milli newton meter
Can anyone show me formula or figure out if this motor will spin a 60 gram circular object at any rpms?
This is a DC motor brushless.

Comment: If I am missing any information please let me know and thank you for help

Comment: 35MNM is a lot of torque : do you mean 35mNm?

Comment: Yes sorry on cell phone milli newton meter

Comment: I have more information on motor if I need to post more

Comment: Doh! If only your motor could do 242.43 W, there would be a perfect solution.

Comment: I'm confused Olin what you mean I'm new to electric

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some basic physics.

Simply spinning a mass at a fixed rate by itself takes no power at all.  It does take power to get it there, with more power required the faster you want to get it up to speed.

At a fixed speed, the power to keep it at that speed is only to overcome friction and losses in the motor.  It has nothing to do with the mass being spun, other than the weight of that mass probably has some effect on the friction.

Comment: Can you tell me what I am.missing please help. Will this motor work ?

Comment: I did. - - - - -

Comment: Now I understand what formula do I use

Comment: @Jman: Same formula that determines how many tomatoes to eat based on the color of your car.